# Needs array not working in route (while works in controller)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a **[needs]** rule in several controllers which works something like:

```
const { computed } = Ember;
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['controller:clients','controller:clients/client'],
  relationship: computed.alias('controllers.clients/client.model'),
  client: computed.alias('relationship.giver'),
}
```

This allows me to pick up the client ID I need as a parameter to the **model** function in my "clients.client[:id].sessions" route. It's pretty darn ugly but it completely works in the controller. In the route, however, this almost identical code:

```
const { computed } = Ember;
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  needs: ['controller:clients','controller:clients/client'],
  relationship: computed.alias('controllers.clients/client.model'),
  client: computed.alias('relationship.giver'),
}
```

... does not resolve. All of the computed properties are left "undefined". Can anyone help me understand why?

> Note: I'd also be happy to incorporate some other way of achieving this same goal in a more compact way ... the pattern I'm solving for is a nested route where a parameter "up the stack" is needed to resolve a model. In my case the **client.id** is needed as a parameter in the model query for *sessions*.

Answer (score 1):

Route's don't support the `needs` construct.  You can either use `controllerFor` in the `setupController` or `modelFor` in `afterModel` / `model` / `setupController` hooks.  This is all assuming the controller/model you are trying to access is in a parent route/resource.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model);
    this.set('client', this.controllerFor('foo').get('model.relationship.giver'));
    this.set('client', this.modelFor('foo').get('relationship.giver'));
  }
}
```